# Time not displayed

Tags: javascript, date, alert

```
alert("hello");

var d = Date();
//alert(d);
var currHour = d.getHours();
document.write(currHour);

function display1(currHour) {

    if(currHour > 1) {
        alert("good morning");
    } else {
        alert("ok bye" + currHour);
    }
}
```

The hello alert shows fine, date also shows fine, however currHour is undefined i don't know 
what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are not passing an argument to `display1` when you call it. Your current code will result in an error because of `d.getHours()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var d = new Date();
```

You are missing the `new` keyword. [new [MDN]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/new)

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EUQGr/)

Answer (score 0):

Per ECMA-262 section 15.9.2, the Date constructor, when called as a function, `returns a String representing the current time (UTC).`